# xsd schema: How to omit namespace prefix in XML instance document

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, prefix

I have this XML schema:

```xml
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:r="urn:rt"
        targetNamespace="urn:rt">

    <element name="RTC">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="Nodes"/>
                <element name="Edges"/>
                ...
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    ...
</schema>
```

and this XML instance document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:rt rt.xsd"
         xmlns:r="urn:rt">

    <r:RTC>
        <Nodes/>
        <Edges/>
        ...
    </r:RTC>
    ...
</catalog>
```

I want to generate a XML schema for already existing XML files. These files do not have this `r:` prefix for the top-most element (i.e. the top-most element is just `<RTC>...</RTC>)`.

Is there a way to be able to omit the `r:` prefix in the instance document?

Comment: Working with elements from different namespaces (which having some in no namespace and others in a certain namespace) requires, I think, to write two schema modules, one for each target namespace, and to import the second schema into the first, to reference elements or types from the schema for the second (target) namespace.

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions: (a) how to generate a schema that matches your existing instance documents, and (b) how to generate instance documents that match your existing schema. Which is it that you want?

Comment: @MichaelKay I am not asking how to generate neither. The provided instance document conforms to the schema and I know how to validate that. I am asking if there is a way to not have this `r:` namespace prefix for the elements in the instance document (possibly by modifying the attributes of the `<schema>` or `<catalog>` elements) and still have them match.

Comment: The provided instance does not conform to the provided schema.